# Android SQLITE Bindings for API14

Tags: android, sqlite, tree, android-ndk

I need to use the R* tree module from SQLITE. To enable that I know that I have to compile it with Android NDK using an additional flag ("-DSQLITE_ENABLE_RTREE=1"), the problem is that my Android application has a minimum minSdkVersion=14 and the bindings available at the official site (https://www.sqlite.org/android/brlist) support only api 15 and above.

Is it possible to enable the R* tree module for api 14? If yes, where can I find the android binding?

Comment: `api-level-15` is a separate branch.